# STL - map containing a vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a map containing a string and a vector:
    `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > sorted_data;`
The string is a persons name and the vector stores the ages of people with that name.

How do I access the vector to print out it's contents and perform calculations such as average on the data.

Any other explanation on the syntax and logic would be really useful as I am struggling with this.

Hope you can help.

Andrew

Comment: Like `sorted_data["jim"][2] += 3;`.

Comment: the same way you do it with *any* map...

Comment: Access which of the many vectors in your map?

Comment: Why a person needs a vector of ages?

Comment: @billz: it's not a person, it's a name.

Comment: Access e.g cycle through all of the data in the map.

Comment: Also Karoly I don't know that's why I asking... Really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map contains many vectors associated with names, so to access one you could write the following, `sorted_data["john"]`. This will give you access to that particular vector.

For example to calculate the average you could iterate over all elements in the vector and sum them up.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < sorted_data["john"].size(); i++)
{
  sum+=sorted_data["john"][i];
}
float avg = sum/(float)sorted_data["john"].size();
```

You could also iterate over the map with iterators. Use the c++ reference [site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/) and try to understand the example code.

Comment: Hey Sigroad. Thanks for the reply. The only problem is that I have populated the map from a text file containing thousands of names. How would I iterate through through every key value without providing the key as text?

Comment: Be aware www.cplusplus.com isn't *THE* c++ reference site but rather *A* reference site and is not endorsed by the standards committee. Some people (not I) have found errors there and recommend www.cppreference.com instead.

Comment: Check out the link! `it->second` gives you the vector so u can iterate over that.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Good information. I've got it working now. :)